# Jupyter notebook running slow in Microsoft Azure

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-notebooks

I am quite new to using Microsoft Azure for running jupyter notebooks. I noticed that it can take 30-45 seconds to polar plot 2 numpy arrays, which is small relatively small (<300 datapoints per array). When I have to execute several of these plots, the time adds up, so I am wondering if this is related to a particular compute instance or network latency? Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Notebook will be slow when the data loading limits are high, below is one of the case where I faced similar issue.

- Tried to display some 40000 columns, I faced some serious unresponsive issue and slowness.
- As soon as I changed the code to display only 40 or 80 columns, the response was good.

Below are some root causes for this:

- Clean all the data which is related to dataframes like pandas etc.
- From the below block we can get memory and cpu usage, so that it will help us to clear the unwanted data:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import psutil
  # gives a single float value
  psutil.cpu_percent()
  # gives an object with many fields
  psutil.virtual_memory()
  # you can convert that object to a dictionary 
  dict(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict())
  # you can have the percentage of used RAM
  psutil.virtual_memory().percent
  79.2
  # you can calculate percentage of available memory
  psutil.virtual_memory().available * 100 / psutil.virtual_memory().total
  20.8
  ```
- We will have some variable inspectors, if they are enabled the notebook might get slow because of some dataframes like pandas. [GIT Issue](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1275)

  If you want to disable it --> Edit --> nbextensions config.

Refer to these SO ([SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505460/why-does-jupyter-notebook-suddenly-slow-down-so-much), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python), [SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025112/jupyter-notebook-is-extremely-slow-when-re-running-cells), [SO4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774322/jupyter-notebook-is-slow-laggy-even-with-refreshed-kernel-and-no-outputs-cells)) links for detailed explanations.